Showing that a group of order $231$ is a semi direct product
I am having a real hard time with this problem. My understanding is that to show that $G$ is a semi direct product, I must find 2 subgroups of $G$ such that one is normal, they have trivial intersection, and their product is $G$. From Sylow theorem I get that the number of Sylow $7$ is 1, so is the number of Sylow $11$, but the number of Sylow $3$ is either $1$ or $7$. However, from here I have not idea where to go. I tried since $C_{11}$ was normal to show $G = C_{11} \rtimes H$ for $H$ a subgroup of order $21$, but I got no where with that (Specifically I found that we have a group of order 21 of the form $PQ$ for $P$ a Sylow 3 and $Q$ a Sylow 7 (which is normal so its a subgroup), however these groups are both normal, so from this we just get the direct product and by CRT just $C_{231}$ so this doesn't help). Then I saw this post: Classify all groups of order 231 = 3.7.11 (and yes, I've seen every post on groups of order $231$ on this site and none of them answer this), in which it states that every group of order $231$ is a semi direct product of the form $G = H \rtimes C_3$ for $H$ a subgroup of order $77$. However, I have no idea how this was found. How do you even prove such a thing for the general case?

You can use the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem - every group $G$ with a Normal subgroup $N$ (e.g the order 7 or order 11  subgroups you found) whose quotient $G/N$ is of coprime order to $N$ is a semidirect product of the two.

You say that you know there is exactly one Sylow-7-subgroup. Call it $X$, then $X$ is normal in $G$.
You say that you know there is exactly one Sylow-11-subgroup. Call it $Y$, then $Y$ is normal in $G$.
By the normality we then have that $XY=YX$ and so $XY$ is a subgroup, and its order is $|X||Y|/|X\cap Y|=77$. Moreover, since $g^{-1}XYg=g^{-1}Xgg^{-1}Yg=XY$, we have that $N:=XY$ is normal.
Now let $D$ be a Sylow-3-subgroup. As $N$ is normal we have that $ND=DN$, so that $ND$ is a subgroup. As it is bigger than $N$ it must be $G$.
Hence $G$ is a semi-direct product of a group of order $77$ by a group of order $3$.
